# NUnit with VS2010 and MVC3

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nunit, asp.net-mvc-3

I installed NUnit 2.5.9 under VS2010 and would like to make it run with the freshly released MVC3.
Following 
http://www.nuclex.org/downloads/tools/39-nunit-template-for-asp-net-mvc-2 
I cannot achieve to make NUnit show up as a Test Framework in the MVC3-New Project template.
Neither do I see NUnit as a template when adding a project.

How to achive it to have NUnit work with MVC 3?

Comment: After installing VS2010 SP1 this works automatically

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Marcus Kimpenhaus created a Visual Studio 2010 extension for this purpose:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7f3bdc82-f418-41aa-ad15-f1d6f89df47a

It worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I've found the answer on my own:
Marcus Kimpenhaus posted a solution which includes a batch file for implementation.

See: http://blog.kimpenhaus.de/2010/12/16/asp-net-mvc-3-with-nunit-testproject-updated-template/

Thank you very much Marcus for your work

Edited: Link has changed inside Markus Kimpenhaus' blog

Comment: Now Link works again: Edited: Link has changed inside Markus Kimpenhaus' blog